# How can I use <ng-content> with routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

In my view *group-summary.component.html* I have:

```
<div class="row">
   <div>
     <app-apple-details *ngIf="isAppleRouteActivated" [someDetails]="detailsToShow" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"></app-apple-details>
     <app-kiwi-details *ngIf="isKiwiRouteActivated" [someDetails]="detailsToShow" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"></app-kiwi-details>
   </div>

   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As you can see which component will be displayed is determinate by simple flag in `GroupSummaryComponent`.

```
isAppleRouteActivated: boolean = this.router.url.indexOf("/category/apple") > -1;
isKiwiRouteActivated: boolean = this.router.url.indexOf("/category/kiwi") > -1;
```

IMO this solution isn't elegant and I think it's hack.

And this is my routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: "groups/:id/category", component: GroupSummaryComponent, children: [
            { path: "apple", loadChildren: "app/features/apple.module#AppleModule" },
            { path: "kiwi", loadChildren: "app/features/kiwi.module#KiwiModule" }
        ]
    }
];
```

So as you can notice `AppleDetailsComponent` (`app-apple-details`) and `KiwiDetailsComponent` (`app-kiwi-details`) are not in routing for now.

**Question:**

I wondering whether is possible to instead of `ngIf` use `<ng-content>` in `GroupSummaryComponent` so if user navigate to `groups/:id/category/apple` then in `<ng-content>` will have `app-apple-details` and the rest will be the same so in `<router-outlet>` will be loaded childrens (`AppleModule`) in this case. But I don't know how to put `AppleDetailsComponent` to `<ng-content>` using routing. Because I don't see any other way to solve this problem.

The reason why I need this - is because I want to have this parent component `GroupSummaryComponent` reusable. For Apple and Kiwi route.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-content` is used to add HTML to components when they are called. This is not used for routing.

Why would you use routing if you don't route your components ? Simply route them and you won't have to use *ngIf or ng-content ...

Otherwise you need to tell us why you're handling "routing" like that, or provide us with an example so that we can fiddle with it.

Comment: So how should I put `app-apple-details` there for `groups/:id/category/apple` route and `kiwi-apple-details` for `groups/:id/category/kiwi`?

Comment: I was trying to use <route-outlet name=""> but I didn't know how to pass arguments from parent. Like in my case `[someDetails]="detailsToShow"`

Comment: But there is nothing about passing argument via `<router-outlet name>`